# How can I detect Fiddler as a proxy on my server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

Does Fiddler add anything to a request that I can use to detect, on the server, when I am using it as a proxy?

I currently [add a header](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/ModifyRequestOrResponse) to every request using `OnBeforeRequest` to show Fiddler is being used as a proxy (but I keep forgetting to do it so I would like a more reliable option).

*Someone is bound to ask why ... we are testing a web api and mvc application, and want to perform certain actions when we attach Fiddler. This is the simplest of several options, but it would be nice to not have to remember to add a detectable request header through `OnBeforeRequest`*

Comment: You can get Fiddler to add a header, would that be a suitable solution?

Comment: @DavidG - that's what I'm already doing (I mentioned it in the question) but various team members forget to do that and then wonder why they aren't seeing the test data. I just wondered if Fiddler added any "fingerprint" by default.

Comment: Generally speaking, there's no "passive" fingerprint that you can use to detect Fiddler. There are a variety of approaches you might try to "actively" detect Fiddler by running JavaScript in a client browser.

Comment: @EricLaw - wow, thank you - straight from the voice of authority.

Comment: @EricLaw Could you please let me know some of these approaches you are mentioning to detect Fiddler using Javascript?

Comment: The problem is that most folks looking to remotely discover whether Fiddler is running are malware authors trying to avoid detection.

Comment: There are ways to detect it certainly... There's a website that blocks most login attempts using Fiddler while allowing to log in without it. They're using Recaptcha v3 so I assume its score depends on something that differs when you use Fiddler as a proxy. My first guess was that they consider not using HTTP/2 or SPDY a suspicious fact but after disabling it in FF I still could log in without Fiddler. I'm kinda stuck here right now, will continue googling I guess.

Comment: In fact, there's probably a pure server-side passive way to detect Fiddler. 
I'm currently using FF with dev tools + Fiddler. Sending the same AJAX request from FF using the Network panel (Resend command). It's returning a correct 200 response when sent with Fiddler disabled and 403 Forbidden response when sent with Fiddler enabled. No other requests are being sent. Just this one. No parameters differ between requests, they are exactly the same according to the dev tools. No cookies are used in the request.
I've disabled HTTP/2 and SPDY; disabled IPv6 in Fiddler and FF.